# Relational Select with condition

Tags: mysql

This is the select I'm doing:

```
$query = "SELECT gestiondoc_publicados_tags.tag FROM gestiondoc_publicados_tags, gestionDoc_publicados_permisos WHERE gestionDoc_publicados_permisos.id_publicado = gestiondoc_publicados_tags.id_publicado AND gestionDoc_publicados_permisos.cargo = :cargo";
```

The table gestiondoc_publicados_tags is like:

```
| id | tag | id_publicado |
| 1  | tag1|       1      |
| 2  | tag2|       1      |
```

The table gestiondoc_publicados_permisos is like:

```
| id | cargo   | id_publicado |
| 1  | cargo1  |       1      |
| 2  | cargo2  |       1      |
```

I want to get every tag where the id_publicado is equal to the id_publicado where cargo is equal to cargo1, but I'm only getting tag1 as the result, how can I do the query properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $query="select q.tag from gestiondoc_publicados_tags as q inner join gestiondoc_publicados_permisos as p on p.id_publicado=q.id_publicado where p.cargo='cargo1'";
```

You have to create a good RDMS.
Please change you foreign Key value for it other than 1.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use  a simple inner join,use the below query:

```
SELECT tags.tag as tags FROM gestiondoc_publicados_tags as ptags INNER JOIN gestiondoc_publicados_tags  as gtags ON ptags.id_publicado  = gtags.id_publicado
```